# Myetherwallet doesn't show my balance

Tags: ether, balances, myetherwallet

I sent some ether to a myetherwallet address. When I load up the wallet info page it says 0 ETH balance, but the link to the etherscan.io address shows the correct balance.

Comment: Can't currently see balances on MEW. It is stuck on loading. But etherscan does show that everything is there. Is there any particular problem atm that's causing this?

Answer (score -3):

Bitcoin transactions take about 30 minutes to receive 3 confirmations and be considered complete, while ether transactions require 50 network confirmations and about the same time. All transactions should be visible to both parties as soon as sent.

Try to wait and confirm to both parties if the trasfer succeeded.

Comment: 50? Where did you get that number from?

Comment: At the time of my question the transaction had a little over 100 confirmations and didn't show up. Today, when I checked again MEW now shows my balance correctly. I'm not 100% convinced your answer was correct, but it seems the best guess.